Running multiple slide shows on the same page
I have a problem with 3 slide shows on my html.
The first one works perfectly fine. its job is to hide 3 different divs and show them when the user wants to interactes with them. div 1 is automactly shown up front by default. div 1 contains a FlexSlider 2 slide show with a carousel. it also works perfectly fine. div 2 is just a simple iframe no problem. div 3 also contains FlexSlider 2 slide with a carousel. this is the problem for some reason the 3rd div doesnt load properly.the expectaion was to have 3 divs and be able to hid two divs at a time and change bewteen the three of them at will. two of the dives will then have a fancier slide show.
i test the code and java scipt with all three divs not hidding and the 2 slides works well. i tested with the iframe hidding and both FlexSlider 2 didnt work well. so my conclusion is that its because the div is hidding at first load causeses the flesslider slide to not work. here is my html:
<div id="tours">
   <div id="ambiance_tours" class="tour_slides">
      <div class="tour_windows flexslider" id="ambiance_slider">
         <ul class="slides">
            <li>
               <img src="images/tours/ambiance/photo_1.png" style="width:100%"/>
               <div class="counter">
                  1/30
               </div>
            </li>
            <li>
               <img src="images/tours/ambiance/photo_2.png" style="width:100%"/>
               <div class="counter">
                  2/30
               </div>
            </li>
            <li>
               <img src="images/tours/ambiance/photo_3.png" style="width:100%"/>
               <div class="counter">
                  3/30
               </div>
            </li>
            <li>
               <img src="images/tours/ambiance/photo_4.png" style="width:100%"/>
               <div class="counter">
                  4/30
               </div>
            </li>
            <li>
               <img src="images/tours/ambiance/photo_5.png" style="width:100%"/>
               <div class="counter">
                  5/30
               </div>
            </li>
            <li>
               <img src="images/tours/ambiance/photo_6.png" style="width:100%"/>
               <div class="counter">
                  6/30
               </div>
            </li>
            <li>
               <img src="images/tours/ambiance/photo_7.png" style="width:100%"/>
               <div class="counter">
                  7/30
               </div>
            </li>
            <li>
               <img src="images/tours/ambiance/photo_8.png" style="width:100%"/>
               <div class="counter">
                  8/30
               </div>
            </li>
            <li>
               <img src="images/tours/ambiance/photo_9.png" style="width:100%"/>
               <div class="counter">
                  9/30
               </div>
            </li>
            <li>
               <img src="images/tours/ambiance/photo_10.png" style="width:100%"/>
               <div class="counter">
                  10/30
               </div>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="ambiance_slider_navigation">
         <a class="main_slide_button main_slide_button_left flex-prev">
            <p>Back</p>
         </a>
         <a class="main_slide_button main_slide_button_right flex-next">
            <p>Next</p>
         </a>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel_holder">
         <div class="preview_windows flexslider" id="ambiance_carousel">
            <ul class="slides">
               <li>
                  <img src="images/tours/ambiance/prev_1.png" style="width:100%"/>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="images/tours/ambiance/prev_2.png" style="width:100%"/>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="images/tours/ambiance/prev_3.png" style="width:100%"/>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="images/tours/ambiance/prev_4.png" style="width:100%"/>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="images/tours/ambiance/prev_5.png" style="width:100%"/>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="images/tours/ambiance/prev_6.png" style="width:100%"/>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="images/tours/ambiance/prev_7.png" style="width:100%"/>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="images/tours/ambiance/prev_8.png" style="width:100%"/>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="images/tours/ambiance/prev_9.png" style="width:100%"/>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="images/tours/ambiance/prev_10.png" style="width:100%"/>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="ambiance_carousel_navigation">
            <a class="carousel_slide_button carousel_button_left flex-prev">
               <p>Back</p>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel_slide_button carousel_button_right flex-next">
               <p>Next</p>
            </a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="inside_view_tours" class="tour_slides">
      <div class="tour_windows">
         <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m0!3m2!1sen!2sca!4v1485235528152!6m8!1m7!1spIAg_DbIVMYAAAQvxTQ9qg!2m2!1d43.69323850777401!2d-79.74551582428109!3f57.606204775495414!4f-3.345146756284393!5f0.7820865974627469" width="850px" height="400px" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="promo_events_tours" class="tour_slides">
      <div class="tour_windows flexslider" id="promo_slider">
         <ul class="slides">
            <li>
               <img src="images/tours/ambiance/photo_1.png" style="width:100%">
            </li>
            <li>
               <img src="images/tours/ambiance/photo_2.png" style="width:100%"/>
            </li>
            <li>
               <img src="images/tours/ambiance/photo_3.png" style="width:100%"/>
            </li>
            <li>
               <img src="images/tours/ambiance/photo_4.png" style="width:100%"/>
            </li>
            <li>
               <img src="images/tours/ambiance/photo_5.png" style="width:100%"/>
            </li>
            <li>
               <img src="images/tours/ambiance/photo_6.png" style="width:100%"/>
            </li>
            <li>
               <img src="images/tours/ambiance/photo_7.png" style="width:100%"/>
            </li>
            <li>
               <img src="images/tours/ambiance/photo_8.png" style="width:100%"/>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="promo_slider_navigation">
         <a class="main_slide_button main_slide_button_left flex-prev">
            <p>Back</p>
         </a>
         <a class="main_slide_button main_slide_button_right flex-next">
            <p>Next</p>
         </a>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel_holder">
         <div class="preview_windows flexslider" id="promo_carousel">
            <ul class="slides">
               <li>
                  <img src="images/tours/ambiance/prev_1.png" style="width:100%"/>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="images/tours/ambiance/prev_2.png" style="width:100%"/>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="images/tours/ambiance/prev_3.png" style="width:100%"/>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="images/tours/ambiance/prev_4.png" style="width:100%"/>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="images/tours/ambiance/prev_5.png" style="width:100%"/>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="images/tours/ambiance/prev_6.png" style="width:100%"/>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="images/tours/ambiance/prev_7.png" style="width:100%"/>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="images/tours/ambiance/prev_8.png" style="width:100%"/>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="promo_carousel_navigation">
            <a class="carousel_slide_button carousel_button_left flex-prev">
               <p>Back</p>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel_slide_button carousel_button_right flex-next">
               <p>Next</p>
            </a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<script>
   let slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);
                            
    function currentSlide(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }
    
    function showSlides(n) {
      let i;
      let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("tour_slides");
      let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("tour_buttons");
      if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
      if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";  
      }
      for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
      dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    }
</script>
</div>


here is my test sight
https://xaymacarestaurant.com/new/test.html
under visual tour section
